# Excel Macro for Importing Text File with fixed width using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Currently I'm using this code to import, delete and converting the text file to CSV file. And I'm doing all of this automatically while targeting the files location and the output location. The code is as the following:

```
Option Explicit


Sub DataConversion()

    Dim directory As String, FileName As String, file As Object, i As Integer, j As Integer, fso As Object, c As Integer, MyFile As String, Content As String, textline As String, TextFileArray As Variant
    Dim Path As String, TextFile As Integer, TotalFile As Integer, TFArray As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    directory = "C:\Users\Edward\Desktop\Extracted Data\Text File"
    FileName = Dir(directory & "*.txt")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set file = fso.GetFolder(directory).Files
    MyFile = "C:\Users\Edward\Desktop\Extracted Data\Text File\*.txt"
    TextFileArray = GetFileList(MyFile)
    TotalFile = file.Count
    Select Case IsArray(TextFileArray)
        Case True
            For i = LBound(TextFileArray) To UBound(TextFileArray)
                TFArray = TextFileArray(i)
                TFArray = Replace(TFArray, ".txt", "")
                ActiveSheet.Cells.ClearContents
                With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
                "TEXT;C:\Users\Edward\Desktop\Extracted Data\Text File\" + TextFileArray(i), _
                Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
                    .Name = TFArray
                    .FieldNames = True
                    .RowNumbers = False
                    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
                    .PreserveFormatting = True
                    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
                    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
                    .SavePassword = False
                    .SaveData = True
                    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
                    .RefreshPeriod = 0
                    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
                    .TextFilePlatform = 437
                    .TextFileStartRow = 1
                    .TextFileParseType = xlFixedWidth
                    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
                    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
                    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
                    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
                    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
                    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
                    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
                    .TextFileFixedColumnWidths = Array(7, 22, 100, 14, 12, 11, 21, 20)
                    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
                    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
                 End With
            Rows("2:2").Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
            ActiveWorkbook.Save
            ChDir "C:\Users\Edward\Desktop\Extracted Data\CSV File"
            ActiveSheet.SaveAs FileName:= _
            "C:\Users\Edward\Desktop\Extracted Data\CSV File\" + TFArray + ".csv", FileFormat:= _
            xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
            Dim wb_connection As WorkbookConnection
            For Each wb_connection In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
                If InStr(TextFileArray(i), wb_connection.Name) > 0 Then
                wb_connection.Delete
                End If
            Next wb_connection
            Next i
        Case False
            MsgBox "No matching files"
    End Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True


End Sub
```

The Code runs fine but it displace the file by 1, example: File_1, File_2, File_3. When it calls the file it should target File_1 first and then only File_2 but instead of doing that the code is taking File_2 first and skipping File_1.

And the output is not as expected because the column width always change between each files and that causes the content to be split into different columns. The part where all the process happens I take from a previous macro that I have recorded.

Is there a way to make the column width change according to the text file? And how do I make the code to select the first file in the location instead of the second file?

Please help me.

EDIT: The width of the column for each file is unknown to me as there are about 300 plus files that I need to convert. However I found that there is a way to detect the width of the column using Transpose function. The code that found are as shown:

```
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim odWS As Worksheet
Dim fsuWS As Worksheet
Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim fcInt As Integer
Dim fcStr As String
Dim spAr As Variant
Dim dtAr As Variant

    Set WB = ThisWorkbook
    Set odWS = WB.Sheets.Add
    odWS.Name = "OriginalData"
    Set fsuWS = WB.Sheets("FieldSetUp")

    'Transposing the range is essential for loading the values to the
    'Array properties below
    spAr = Application.Transpose(fsuWS.Range("SpanSpaces").Value)
    dtAr = Application.Transpose(fsuWS.Range("ImpDataTypes").Value)
```

The part that interest me is the 
`spAr = Application.Transpose(fsuWS.Range("SpanSpaces").Value)`
and 
`dtAr = Application.Transpose(fsuWS.Range("ImpDataTypes").Value)`
as these are the parts that I need for me to make the macro to determine the width of the column. But I don't know what does `"SpanSpaces"` and `"ImpDataTypes"` do and what are their uses but I think it is just a Variant that have been declare earlier. Is there a way for me to change this two lines of code to make it fit my current one?

The whole code and post that I found this code can be found over here:
http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/676605-fill-array-property-range-variable.html

Comment: If *' the column width always change between each files'* then obviously you cannot use a fixed width format. Use a delimited format with all delimiters turned off except the comma.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that part, I have notice that the `.TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)`
 `.TextFileFixedColumnWidths = Array(7, 22, 100, 14, 12, 11, 21, 20)`
Is what causes the the whole thing to get jumble up. But the reason why i use fixed field is because the file that I import in doesn't contain any kind of separator like comma, space or even tab.

Comment: So if there are no delimiters and no file is guaranteed to be in a fixed width format, you must have a parsing strategy? E.g. if the content of each line is RedOrangeYellowGreenBlueIndigoViolet then you can say you want to split the line on capital letters.

Comment: What is `GetFileList`?  Is it that each file is different column widths but you know what each one will be, or they're all just random unknown widths?  If it's the second of those it's going to be difficult to automate this process.

Comment: As long as you know what the widths are, you can use an `If Else` where you directly select the `FixedColumnWidths`. Or if it is always like your example then also something like `Array(, Array(7, 22, 100), Array(9, 12, 102))(Right(TFArray, 1))` will do.

Comment: The width of each of the files are unknown to me as there are too many for me to check. The `GetFileList` is a function that I use to get the file names. And sadly my files contains both Alphabets and Numbers as there.